# Android measure view visible area

Tags: android, android-layout

I have been searching a lot of similar answer from here, but none can work accurately. I want to calculate the visible area of a custom view, the view can be blocked by the screen edge, or block by the edge of scroll view, let see the picture below:

[image]

As above, black color is my screen, red color is my custom view and scroll up a bit, I want to measure area of B.

[image]

As above, black color is my screen, red color is my custom view, blue color is scroll view. Custom view is child of the scroll view and it is scroll up a bit. I want to measure area of B.

1) I have tried, `View.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame`, `View.getLocalVisibleRect`, `View.getGlobalVisibleRect`, but none of it work accurately. First glance they looks good, but when I scroll my view disappear from screen, somehow, it show me the full height and width of the view, which the view is not even displayed within the screen.

2) I tried `View.getLocationOnScreen()` and `getLocationInWindow()` to calculate the offset manually, get XY coordination and plus/minus the view's (and screen) height and width, but found it not easy too, because the top of screen always have extra menu bar or etc, and will mess out with the result.

3) Although this is not likely in my situation, I want to know, if there is a absolute layout on top of my view and partially block it, can I still find out the area? (both layout are in same activity)

My question is, is there any easy and accurate way to calculate the area I want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer from one of the open source Ad framework:

```
/**
 * Whether the view is at least certain % visible
 */
boolean isVisible(@Nullable final View rootView, @Nullable final View view, final int minPercentageViewed) {
    // ListView & GridView both call detachFromParent() for views that can be recycled for
    // new data. This is one of the rare instances where a view will have a null parent for
    // an extended period of time and will not be the main window.
    // view.getGlobalVisibleRect() doesn't check that case, so if the view has visibility
    // of View.VISIBLE but it's group has no parent it is likely in the recycle bin of a
    // ListView / GridView and not on screen.
    if (view == null || view.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE || rootView.getParent() == null) {
        return false;
    }

    if (!view.getGlobalVisibleRect(mClipRect)) {
        // Not visible
        return false;
    }

    // % visible check - the cast is to avoid int overflow for large views.
    final long visibleViewArea = (long) mClipRect.height() * mClipRect.width();
    final long totalViewArea = (long) view.getHeight() * view.getWidth();

    if (totalViewArea <= 0) {
        return false;
    }

    return 100 * visibleViewArea >= minPercentageViewed * totalViewArea;
}
```

I made a mistake while I am using `View.getGlobalVisibleRect`, when the view disappear from the screen, this method will return false, although the `mClipRect` object still providing value. Above is the correct way in using it.

Comment: `int overflow for large views` it's like for views 50k by 50k pixels? lol

Comment: can you tell me what the mClipRect variable is? @GMsoF

Comment: @rbd_sqrl that is the empty `Rect` object, you need to create a new and empty Rect object and pass it into the method, after that, you will get your rectangle dimension which you need, that dimension represent your visible view area. Refer to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html

Answer (score 0):

During implementing a new feature "ViewHierarchy" in my work at [Instabug](https://instabug.com/) I face the same problem and fix this problem through the below code

This is util class that does all the logic

```
public class ViewFrameInspector {

private static final String KEY_X = "x";
private static final String KEY_Y = "y";
private static final String KEY_W = "w";
private static final String KEY_H = "h";

/**
 * Method emit inspected ViewFrame of passed view, the emit ViewFrame contains inspected ViewFrames fot its children and children of the children and so on
 * by converting the emitted ViewFrame to list of View Frames you can find the a specific view and its frame with easily way
 *
 * @param view the root view
 * @return return ViewFrame observable
 */
public static Observable<ViewFrame> inspectRootViewFrameRx(final View view) {

    return Observable.defer(new Func0<Observable<ViewFrame>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<ViewFrame> call() {
            ViewFrame rootViewFrame = new ViewFrame();
            rootViewFrame.setRoot(true);
            rootViewFrame.setView(view);
            return Observable.just(inspectVisibleViewFrame(rootViewFrame));
        }
    });
}

private static ViewFrame inspectVisibleViewFrame(final ViewFrame viewFrame) {
    if (viewFrame.getView().getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
        try {
            viewFrame.setId(inspectViewResourceId(viewFrame.getView().getContext(), viewFrame.getView().getId()));
            viewFrame.setType(ViewFrameInspector.inspectViewType(viewFrame.getView()));
            viewFrame.setOriginalRect(ViewFrameInspector.inspectViewOriginalRect(viewFrame.getView()));
            viewFrame.setVisibleRect(ViewFrameInspector.inspectViewVisibleRect(viewFrame));
            viewFrame.setFrame(ViewFrameInspector.inspectViewFrame(viewFrame));
            // inspect view children if exist
            if (viewFrame.getView() instanceof ViewGroup) {
                viewFrame.setHasChildren(true);
                inspectViewChildren(viewFrame);
            } else {
                viewFrame.setHasChildren(false);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(ActivityViewInspector.class.getSimpleName(), "inspect view frame got error: " + e.getMessage() + ",view id:" + viewFrame.getId() + ", time in MS: " + System.currentTimeMillis(), e);
        }
    return viewFrame;
}

private static void inspectViewChildren(ViewFrame parentViewFrame) throws JSONException {
    if (parentViewFrame.getView() instanceof ViewGroup) {
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) parentViewFrame.getView();
        for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
            ViewFrame childViewFrame = new ViewFrame();
            childViewFrame.setRoot(false);
            childViewFrame.setView(parent.getChildAt(i));
            childViewFrame.setParent(parentViewFrame);
            parentViewFrame.addNode(inspectVisibleViewFrame(childViewFrame));
        }
    }
}

private static String inspectViewType(View view) {
    return view.getClass().getSimpleName();
}

private static String inspectViewResourceId(Context context, int id) throws JSONException {
    try {
        return context != null && context.getResources() != null && context.getResources().getResourceEntryName(id) != null ?
                context.getResources().getResourceEntryName(id) : String.valueOf(id);
    } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
        return String.valueOf(id);
    }
}

private static Rect inspectViewOriginalRect(View view) {
    int[] locationOnScreen = new int[2];
    view.getLocationOnScreen(locationOnScreen);
    return new Rect(locationOnScreen[0],
            locationOnScreen[1],
            locationOnScreen[0] + view.getWidth(),
            locationOnScreen[1] + view.getHeight());
}

private static Rect inspectViewVisibleRect(ViewFrame viewFrame) {
    if (viewFrame.isRoot()) {
        return viewFrame.getOriginalRect();
    } else {
        Rect viewVisibleRect = new Rect(
                viewFrame.getOriginalRect().left,
                viewFrame.getOriginalRect().top,
                viewFrame.getOriginalRect().right,
                viewFrame.getOriginalRect().bottom);
        Rect parentAvailableVisibleRect = new Rect(
                inspectViewAvailableX(viewFrame.getParent()),
                inspectViewAvailableY(viewFrame.getParent()),
                inspectViewAvailableRight(viewFrame.getParent()),
                inspectViewAvailableBottom(viewFrame.getParent()));
        if (viewVisibleRect.intersect(parentAvailableVisibleRect)) {
            return viewVisibleRect;
        } else {
            return new Rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
    }
}

private static int inspectViewAvailableX(ViewFrame viewFrame) {
    int visibleLeft, paddingLeft, originalLeft;
    visibleLeft = viewFrame.getVisibleRect().left;
    paddingLeft = viewFrame.getView().getPaddingLeft();
    originalLeft = viewFrame.getOriginalRect().left;
    if (paddingLeft == 0) {
        return visibleLeft;
    } else {
        if (visibleLeft > (originalLeft + paddingLeft)) {
            return visibleLeft;
        } else {
            return originalLeft + paddingLeft;
        }
    }
}

private static int inspectViewAvailableY(ViewFrame viewFrame) {
    int visibleTop, paddingTop, originalTop;
    visibleTop = viewFrame.getVisibleRect().top;
    paddingTop = viewFrame.getView().getPaddingTop();
    originalTop = viewFrame.getOriginalRect().top;
    if (paddingTop == 0) {
        return visibleTop;
    } else {
        if (visibleTop > (originalTop + paddingTop)) {
            return visibleTop;
        } else {
            return originalTop + paddingTop;
        }
    }
}

private static int inspectViewAvailableRight(ViewFrame viewFrame) {
    int visibleRight, paddingRight, originalRight;
    visibleRight = viewFrame.getVisibleRect().right;
    paddingRight = viewFrame.getView().getPaddingRight();
    originalRight = viewFrame.getOriginalRect().right;
    if (paddingRight == 0) {
        return visibleRight;
    } else {
        if (visibleRight < (originalRight - paddingRight)) {
            return visibleRight;
        } else {
            return originalRight - paddingRight;
        }
    }
}

private static int inspectViewAvailableBottom(ViewFrame viewFrame) {
    int visibleBottom, paddingBottom, originalBottom;
    visibleBottom = viewFrame.getVisibleRect().bottom;
    paddingBottom = viewFrame.getView().getPaddingBottom();
    originalBottom = viewFrame.getOriginalRect().bottom;
    if (paddingBottom == 0) {
        return visibleBottom;
    } else {
        if (visibleBottom < (originalBottom - paddingBottom)) {
            return visibleBottom;
        } else {
            return originalBottom - paddingBottom;
        }
    }
}

private static JSONObject inspectViewFrame(ViewFrame viewFrame) throws JSONException {
    return new JSONObject().put(KEY_X, viewFrame.getVisibleRect().left)
            .put(KEY_Y, viewFrame.getVisibleRect().top)
            .put(KEY_W, viewFrame.getVisibleRect().width())
            .put(KEY_H, viewFrame.getVisibleRect().height());
}

public static List<ViewFrame> convertViewHierarchyToList(ViewFrame viewFrame) {
    ArrayList<ViewFrame> viewFrameHierarchies = new ArrayList<>();
    if (viewFrame != null) {
        viewFrameHierarchies.add(viewFrame);
        if (viewFrame.hasChildren()) {
            for (ViewFrame childViewHierarchy : viewFrame.getNodes()) {
                viewFrameHierarchies.addAll(convertViewHierarchyToList(childViewHierarchy));
            }
        }
    }
    return viewFrameHierarchies;
}

}
```

This is model class that hold all data related to inspected views

```
public class ViewFrame {

private String id;
private String type;
private JSONObject frame;
private ViewFrame parent;
private ArrayList<ViewFrame> nodes;
private boolean hasChildren;
private boolean isRoot;
private Rect originalRect;
private Rect visibleRect;
private View view;

public ViewFrame() {
    nodes = new ArrayList<>();
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public JSONObject getFrame() {
    return frame;
}

public void setFrame(JSONObject frame) {
    this.frame = frame;
}

public ViewFrame getParent() {
    return parent;
}

public void setParent(ViewFrame parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
}

public ArrayList<ViewFrame> getNodes() {
    return nodes;
}

public void addNode(ViewFrame childViewHierarchy) {
    nodes.add(childViewHierarchy);
}

public boolean hasChildren() {
    return hasChildren;
}

public void setHasChildren(boolean hasChildren) {
    this.hasChildren = hasChildren;
}

public boolean isRoot() {
    return isRoot;
}

public void setRoot(boolean root) {
    isRoot = root;
}

public Rect getVisibleRect() {
    return visibleRect;
}

public void setVisibleRect(Rect visibleRect) {
    this.visibleRect = visibleRect;
}

public Rect getOriginalRect() {
    return originalRect;
}

public void setOriginalRect(Rect originalRect) {
    this.originalRect = originalRect;
}

public View getView() {
    return view;
}

public void setView(View view) {
    this.view = view;
}
}
```

Hope this code help you also